# How to write a C# Function that returns a class type speficifed as a parameter?

Tags: c#, function, class, reflection, parameters

I am trying to write a JSON helper class for a C# MVC app that returns a class instance of the type that is specified as a parameter. The intent of this is to simplify deserializing a JSON into a Model of the right type. the Unfortunately i am running into an error of:

> 'ModelType' is a variable but used as a type.

Here is the code I am using:

```
        public ActionResult api_call() {
            // Parse/Map request stream containing a JSON to a C# object
            json_helper _o_json_helper = new json_helper();
            pollread_read_request _request = _o_json_helper.parse_json_to_object(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetType("pollread_read_request"), Request.InputStream); 
            // Create a business logic instance
            Pollmaker_business_logic _business_logic = new Pollmaker_business_logic();
            // process request using business logic
            List<pollread_read_response> _response = _business_logic.api_call(_request);
            // return result
            return Json(_response, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Reflection;
namespace Umbrella.Abstracts {
    public class json_helper {
        public Object parse_json_to_object(Type ClassModelType, System.IO.Stream InputStream) {
            object _result = Activator.CreateInstance(ClassModelType);
            try {
                string _json_request = "";
                using (System.IO.Stream _oRequestStream = InputStream) {
                    _oRequestStream.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    _json_request = new System.IO.StreamReader(_oRequestStream).ReadToEnd();
                }
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(_json_request)) {
                    _result = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ClassModelType> (_json_request);
                }
            } catch { }
            return _result;               
        }
        public json_helper() {}
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't you use generics here? E.g., `public T parse_json_to_object<T>(T model, Stream InputStream) where T : class { }`.  So you have `T _result = null; [...] _result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(_json_request);` Or, you don't have access to the model Types at run-time, for some reason?

Comment: A small note, _The other party is able to construct an instance of a type he sends as text._ Sounds like a possible secutity hole. You need to be sure that it only constructs types you are allow. Somewhere a hashset with allowed types, would be useful. Kinda white-list

Comment: @Jimi sometimes i don't have the model types at runtime or they will be compiled from other projects i don't have access to creating a black box effect.

Comment: This is quite weird. How do you know where to get the Type? `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetType("pollread_read_request")` is not enough to get the Type and create an instance of it (BTW, you really don't need this: `object _result = Activator.CreateInstance(ClassModelType);` or this: `using (System.IO.Stream _oRequestStream = InputStream) { }`). Does the API know?? And what are you going to do with the *Object* you get back? Use reflection to get property names as strings for a binder? --  If this design is your decision, I'd suggest to re-engineer it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the non-generic overload of [DeserializeObject](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject_2.htm).

```
_result = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(_json_request, ClassModelType);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you also tried sending it only the assembly name and type name?

object _result = Activator.CreateInstance(ClassModelType.Assembly.FullName, ClassModelType.Name);